# Remove part of the last element from display from a Wicket ListView

Tags: wicket

I am new to Wicket. I have to implement a `ListView` that contains a `div` between all list items. I am able to do it, but it shows the `div` after last element also. I don't want that last `div` to appear. How can I get rid of it? This is my existing code:

```
    add(new ListView<ItemAdapter>("items", order.getItems()) {
        @Override protected void populateItem(ListItem<ItemAdapter> item)
        ItemAdapter itemList= (ItemAdapter)item.getModelObject();
        item.add(new Label("itemName",  itemList.getItemName()));
        item.add(new Label("qty",itemList.getQuantity().toString()));
        item.add(new Label("div","<br/><div class='itemList'></div>"))
    }
});
```

Answer (score 5):

Set the component's visibility with [`setVisible()`](http://wicket.apache.org/apidocs/1.4/org/apache/wicket/Component.html#setVisible%28boolean%29) according to if the item is the last one in the list, using [`ListItem.getIndex()`](http://wicket.apache.org/apidocs/1.4/org/apache/wicket/markup/html/list/ListItem.html#getIndex%28%29) and the size of [`ListView.getList()`](http://wicket.apache.org/apidocs/1.4/org/apache/wicket/markup/html/list/ListView.html#getList%28%29). If the component is called `setVisible(false)`, it will not be included at all in the rendered output.

Also, I'd recommend to not use a `Label` for the separator. Add it as a `WebMarkupContainer`, and define its contents in the markup (that's where it belongs).

Use a [`wicket:container`](https://cwiki.apache.org/WICKET/wickets-xhtml-tags.html#Wicket%2527sXHTMLtags-Elementwicket%253Acontainer) in the HTML, or use a `<div>` and set `renderBodyOnly(true)` so that only the contents of the `WebMarkupContainer` are output.

For instance:

```
ItemAdapter itemList= (ItemAdapter)item.getModelObject();
item.add(new Label("itemName",  itemList.getItemName()));
item.add(new Label("qty",itemList.getQuantity().toString()));
WebMarkupContainer separator = new WebMarkupContainer("separator");
boolean isLast = item.getIndex() +1 == getList().size();
separator.setVisible(!isLast);
item.add(separator);
```

With the HTML:

```
<div wicket:id="list">
    ...
    <wicket:container wicket:id="separator">
        <br/>
        <div class='itemList'></div>
    </wicket:container>
</div>
```

As a side note, in case you still want to use a `Label` for the separator, you should be using [`separator.setEscapeModelStrings(false);`](http://wicket.apache.org/apidocs/1.4/org/apache/wicket/Component.html#setEscapeModelStrings%28boolean%29) in order to tell Wicket not to escape the markup defined in its Model.

If the `ListView` was paged, for instance, with a `PageableListView`, you should use [`ListView.getViewSize()`](http://wicket.apache.org/apidocs/1.4/org/apache/wicket/markup/html/list/ListView.html#getViewSize%28%29)` to determine the real number of displayed items in the view.

Comment: @Anu: you should accept answers, otherwise people will feel like answering you.